# Why does vue throws an error at myMap.delete (mapKey)?

Tags: vue.js

I want to click on the element to delete the element from the map for this I want to use .delete (mapKey)

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="mapKey of messages.keys()" :key="mapKey">
      <div @click="messages.delete(mapKey)"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      messages: new Map(),
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

But I get the error

```html
Errors compiling template:

  avoid using JavaScript unary operator as property name: "delete(mapKey)" in expression @click="messages.delete(mapKey)"

  2  |  <div class="messenger">
  3  |    <div v-for="mapKey of messages.keys()" :key="mapKey">
  4  |      <div @click="messages.delete(mapKey)"></div>
     |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  5  |    </div>
  6  |  </div>
```

`@click = "delete messages.get (mapKey)"` doesn't work ...
`a @click = "messages.delete (mapKey)"` too ...
ESLint + Prettier + Webpack - Vue 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is to call an inner function named as `delete` directly from `@click`. To fix it, just add a method and call delete from inside a `deleteMessages` method:

```
<div @click="deleteMessages()"></div>
```

And add this after `data()`:

```
methods: {
  deleteMessages() {
    this.messages.delete(mapKey)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks can I ask, if this function is used in many components, is it correct to transfer it to filters or global-mixins?

Comment: Keeping this function centralized is a good idea, so you would not need to implement it again in every component.